# Custom USB distro problem: cannot connect to the Internet

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, internet, custom-distributions

This is my first thread and I would like to apologize for my lack of knowledge regarding forum-based rules.

I intend to make a Custom USB Ubuntu 13.10 Distribution with the applications i need. I did everything i needed, but there is one problem: I cannot connect to the Internet.

I created the distribution after installing the programs I needed (like GIMP and Google Earth) using "remastersys" and "Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator". Whenever i wish to acces the Internet while booted from USB it says there is a connection problem. I can connect to my router and the router gives me a DHCP address. I tried connecting using wired, wireless and USB wireless dongle. However, I pinged Google using terminal and i had 100% responses with no delay.

I am really out of solutions and really need this USB Ubuntu to work on the internet. Thank you for any advice you can give me!

Comment: Post the output from `ifconfig` and `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this off the remastersys forum, as I'm trying to figure this out on 14.04 as well

http://www.remastersys.com/forums/index.php?topic=2729.0

"Network Manager has been changed.  You will have to remove the part in /usr/bin/remastersys that removes $WORKDIR/dummysys/etc/resolv.conf and remaster again.

This is caused by a change to the way they are populating resolv.conf since it is now just a link.  I have to update remastersys for 12.10 which I haven't had a chance to do yet."

I say give that a shot and see - I'm re-making my image right now.